# specific length subdomain location match nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I tried below code.

`location ~* (^.{6})\.example.com`

above regex not working, I want to match the subdomains of length 6 only. i have tested the regex at https://regex101.com/ successfully but in Nginx.conf it is creating syntax issues.

Comment: If the regular expression contains `{}` you need to place it inside `"`s, otherwise Nginx is confused by the first `{` as the beginning of the block. You cannot match domain names using a `location` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names).

Comment: @RichardSmith correct, thank you.